# DataSnap XE2 , Disconnecting with second connection in the same client

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, datasnap, c++builder-xe2

**Hello : This is an important issue about Datasnap XE2 Tcp transport**

I have an old problem , I asked for it before here, but no reply

DataSnap XE2 , Disconnecting with second connection in the same client :

Simple Datasnap server , simple client , ( just call reverse method ) , after few seconds the server destroy one or all the servermethods class , the datasnapserver is tcp protocol , lifecycle=Session , statefull server.

I test the same binary exe on another machines , and another OS ,and I Notice these :

1- The same problem occured when running the server on a computer which linked to router some with WiFi (with / without dhcp ) all OS ( server2003, Win7 ,Winxp ) give the same problem

2- When running the same server on Virtual Machines (all OS ) no problem at all , I use the Oracle Virtual Box , **WHY !**

3- In Server implemntation I Change the TCP Transport to http Transport ,   then i have no problem at all **!.**

4- I test and try every thing possible ( Networking configuration , Reformating , Fresh OS -- all windows versions -- ) the problem on tcp server transport **still**

5- It occures after (20 seconds -2 minutes ) after calling the client method some times in both connections .

6- I made and test new tcp server (not datasnap) and worked fine , **but DataSnapXE2 TCP server made that problem**

Is there some thing to do , I Just need to know why , I need expectations to test , I try almost every thing possible

I use C++Builder XE2 , no updates , all updates available have nothing about this problem 
I also rebuild in Delphi XE2 , the smae problem

is there somebody know **why** , good advise , **please reply**

**Note : DataSnap 2010 , same code , works fine !!**

**Thank you for your reply in advanced**

Answer (score 2):

There is something really wrong with the clientdataset in XE2 which all the follow problems:

1. Socket Server (scktsrvr) terminated due to too many data coming in from .data or as olevariant.
2. Catastrophic Failure of no reason in XE2. Same code works in D2010 simply will not work
   in XE2
3. You will not be able to move your existing DATASNAP from D2010 or XE to XE2. Even if you
   have a complete rewrite from scratch you will get problems.

New Datasnap or Old Datasnap better think twice before moving or wait until bug in XE2 will be settled.

Comment: Is there a QC report for this bug?  We're considering migrating from XE to XE3, so I'd like to follow-up on this issue.